# Jquery .each() on dynamic data issue

Tags: jquery, input, each

I have html input, where users can input any text. Also, users can add more inputs and insert any text too:

```
 <div class="u-form-group" id="1" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Word in Native Language" name="native_word" id="native_word" class="niceinput" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Translation" name="learn_word" id="learn_word" class="niceinput" />
 </div>
```

So imagine there is couple more similar .u-form-group blocks.

On button click I have `.each` which collects value from #native_word from each block.

```
$("#btn-save").click(function() {
    $( ".canvas .u-form-group" ).each(function() {
        var id_div = ".u-form-group#"+$(this).attr('id')+" #native_word";
        alert($(''+id_div).val());
    }); 
});
```

In result on click I receive valid value only from first input (which was manually written in the code). From others I get only - "undentified".

How to make it work properly and collect value from dynamically loaded inputs?

Comment: Are you duplicating html ids? Because that's not a good practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the jQuery [`find`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) function to find the `native_word` input inside of the `each` callback, then access the value with [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```js
$("#btn-save").click(function() {
  $( ".canvas .u-form-group" ).each(function() {
    var nativeWord = $(this).find("input#native_word");
    console.log(nativeWord.val());
  }); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas">
  <div class="u-form-group" id = "1" style = "margin-top:50px;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Word in Native Language" name="native_word" id="native_word" class="niceinput" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Translation" name="learn_word" id="learn_word" class="niceinput" />
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group" id = "2" style = "margin-top:50px;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Word in Native Language" name="native_word" id="native_word" class="niceinput" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Translation" name="learn_word" id="learn_word" class="niceinput" />
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn-save">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should not duplicate ID's. Try using classes and it works.

```js
$("#btn-save").click(function() {
  $(".canvas .u-form-group").each(function() {
    alert($(this).find('.niceinput-native').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="canvas">
  <div class="u-form-group" id="1" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Word in Native Language" name="native_word" class="niceinput-native" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Translation" name="learn_word" class="niceinput-translation" />
  </div>
  <div class="u-form-group" id="2" style="margin-top:50px;">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Word in Native Language" name="native_word" class="niceinput-native" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Translation" name="learn_word" class="niceinput-translation" />
  </div>
</div>
<button id="btn-save">Save</button>
```